# Regex to match certain digit pattern

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex expression that allows me to parse through text files with thousands of lines, and each line contains one number with a variable size of digits.

Each number only can contain either the digits 1 or 0 (zero).

The requirement is there MUST be at least 3 1's in the number, and at least one zero. Therefore, the minimum required size of each number is 4 and it has unlimited maximum.

For example, it has to match:

```
000000111 - has at least 1 zero and 3 ones
1110 - same thing
11111000 - same thing
111 - FAIL, because it's under 4 digits long
0000000011 - FAIL, needs at least 3 ones
```

Can anyone help me please? My problem is that I can't determine how to find 'at least 3 ones and one zero **anywhere** in the number', key word being anywhere.

Comment: If it possible try to sort string and after that check it with regexp `0+1{3,}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match such numbers with:

```
(?=1*0)(?:0*1){3}[10]*
```

`(?=1*0)` make sure there is at least 1 `0` with a lookahead `(?=...)`

`(?:0*1){3}` match the number with 3 `1`s

`[10]*` match the rest or the number

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is strictly a regex exercise/practice, this would be more easily done by hand. (and since the regex would be complicated (im guessing), it would be way more efficient)

```
int ones = 0;
int zeroes = 0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();++i)
{
    if(str[i] = '0')
        ++zeroes;
    else if(str[i] = '1')
        ++ones;
}

if(ones+zeroes >= 4 && ones >=3 && zeroes >= 1)
    return true;
```

Comment: Yes, this is for a regex subject in college, we can't use programming languages, else it would be a lot easier, as you said. Thanks anyway!